# Java and mssql :sqljdbcdriver

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc

I am trying to connect to mssql database using jdbs....................

I have imported "`import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*`";<----import is never used

And have registered the driver manager using
`Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")`;<-----classnotfoundexception

I must add that I have downloaded the jdbc driver and extracted the jar.
I have also added it to the build path in eclipse.
I have just about tried everythimg.

[The snippet of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKkbF.png)

Comment: And the jdbc driver jar is also on the runtime path?

Comment: I see in your code snippet that the line where you are trying to get the class by name is underlined with red. You must have that line in a try...catch block.  You must have modified the code if you are able to compile&run it.

Comment: sorry, could you elaborate?

Comment: do you still have the red underline for the line Class.forName(...)?Does the code compile and you get the exception when you run it, or it does not compile?

Comment: if you do this `try {
   Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerDriver");
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } `  what is the error?

Comment: @Laura Thanks for pointing that out, i have put it in a try catch, but that does not resolve the issue.Upon running it gives a host of errors, the code is directly pulled from Microsoft's website and the only changes i have done is to change the server and instance name.

Comment: another thing you could test is import just the class you need, to see if it is really there, maybe the jar is not good or has been modified. So instead of importing the whole package with *, write the name of the class.

Comment: different errors? or class not found?

Comment: no the red line has gone, but upon building i get errors, should i post the stacktrace?

Comment: also, check that you do not have the same jar twice in the path.

Comment: yes,please post the errors.

Comment: the console is too long and i cant paste it here is there any way to pass it into a file to you. Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea :)  try just the first part, the message

Comment: May 18, 2016 4:11:48 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel enableSSL
INFO: java.security path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\security
Security providers: [SUN version 1.8, SunRsaSign version 1.8, SunEC version 1.8, SunJSSE version 1.8, SunJCE version 1.8, SunJGSS

Comment: it is followed by multiple such lines!

Comment: also i have this warning:

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Build path specifies execution environment OSGi/Minimum-1.2. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.  vertxJdbcDemo  Build path JRE System Library Problem

Comment: warning was due to another issue which is now resolved, but errors continue.

Comment: but this seems to be an INFO, not an error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unsed Import and add the Driver jar (sqljdbc4.jar) to your classpath

Comment: Hi, i've added it to the build path of the eclipse ide and commented out the import yet i get the same error.

Comment: @AdityaChandrayan Read the answer. classpath is not equals buildpath